# Is it possible to simulate UITouch on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitouch

I want to generate touch and then transmit to UIWebView. Is it possible? I don't want use any private SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html blog post by Matt. Shows you how to Synthesize Touch Event on iPhone.

Comment: The above doesn't entirely work any longer. I've created a category, based on it and other contributions, to support our testing framework, Cedar.

It's on the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16471965/1532399