# Swift: Simulate a pan-gesture programmatically

Tags: swift, animation, gesture, pan

I have an animation which is animated with a pan-gesture. When the gesture recognizer state changes the animation proceeds (it's a rotation of a image).

Now I want to show the user in a tutorial that he has to pan/swipe up or down to animate.

Is there a way to "simulate" the translation and velocity of the pan-gesture in order to perform the animation once? The logic of the animation is based on the pan-gesture translation.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368905/how-to-programmatically-send-a-pangesture-in-swift)?  Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Cocoa Touch that does this for you, but you can build your own system.

One way to do this is to define your own `UIPanGestureRecognizer` subclass, `RecordingPanGestureRecognizer`, and build that so that it behaves like a normal gesture recognizer but also saves the timestamped history of all calls it makes on its action target. This can be done just by using the normal target-action mechanism to target two objects. You can save the call history to a file.

Then, also build a `Player` type that can read that recording and replay a similar set of target action events.

With this system, you can manually record a gesture and replay it later. This is approach used in the app where I work, and it works well.