# How do I add a drag gesture in swiftUI so that I change views? Sort of like Snapchat where swiping right gets you to stories?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

So on Snapchat you swipe left to go  to chats, and right  to go to stories/discover. How  can I implement this into my app? Does SwiftUI have this capability with DragGesture()? Or does only UIKit have this and what would the code be please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just researching trying to find how to do it on swiftUI or UIKit and I can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible in swiftUI, but I am not familiar enough to verbalize so I will answer with UIKit since you have implied that UIKit an acceptable answer for you as well.

Here is conceptually one way to do it in UIKit

Add a gesture recognizer to your view. You can see how to do that here:

[How to programmatically send a pangesture in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368905/how-to-programmatically-send-a-pangesture-in-swift)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622496-addgesturerecognizer

Add a second view to the right or left of your view. 
Animate the second view to move based on the movement, and location of the touch.

You could also just have a gesture recognizer that performs a custom segue that animates. Have a custom segue for each direction with a left and right animation navigating to different viewcontrollers.

https://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift**, you can accomplish this by code similar to this:

```
  // First declare and initialize each swipe gesture you want to create.  I have added swipe left and right, to go back and forth between views.

   let rightSwipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
   rightSwipe.direction = .right

   let leftSwipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
   leftSwipe.direction = .left
```

Next you want to handle each swipe, inside a function.

```
@objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

     if sender.direction == .right { // user swiped right
          // push view controller (push new view on the navigation stack)
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController(), animated: true)

     } else { // user swiped left
          // pop view controller (go back one view on the navigation stack)
          self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

     }
}
```