# Swift UIPanGesture

Tags: ios, swift

I was watching a tutorial from this video on how to make a tinder like card swipe gesture. [Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fXR-Ksuqo4). I also used this stack overflow post as well [StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368905/how-to-programmatically-send-a-pangesture-in-swift)

The problem I am having is that my whole screen (all the buttons, labels, views) begins to move as a whole and never returns to the center when using UIPanGesture. [I tried to capture what I mean by move as a whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajz8b.png). My goal is to only move UIView (white box). Here is my code (down below)

```
 let backButton = UIButton()
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "backButton.png"), for: .normal)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(backButton)

    backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 10 ).isActive = true
    backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    let gameTitle = UILabel()
    gameTitle.text = "Slighty Drunk"
    gameTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 33)
    gameTitle.textColor = .white
    gameTitle.textAlignment = .right
    gameTitle.backgroundColor = .black
    self.view.addSubview(gameTitle)

    gameTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    gameTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    gameTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    gameTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210).isActive = true
    gameTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    let gameCard = UIView()
    gameCard.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view.addSubview(gameCard)

    gameCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //gameCard.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
    gameCard.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    gameCard.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor ).isActive = true
    gameCard.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width - 50).isActive = true
    gameCard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.height / 2 + 70).isActive = true


    createPanGestureRecognizer(gameCard)
}


@objc func backButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    //print("Button 1 tapped")
    let homePageStoryBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "homePage", bundle:nil)
    let homePageController = homePageStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage") as UIViewController
    self.present(homePageController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}


func createPanGestureRecognizer(_: UIView) {
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(#selector(self.panCard(_:))))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func panCard (_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let card = sender.view!
    let point = sender.translation(in: view)
    card.center = CGPoint (x: self.view.center.x + point.x, y: self.view.center.y + point.y)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            card.center = self.view.center
        })
    }
```

For now, my goal is only to move the UIView (white box) and have it return to the center when the person lets go of the view. Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved the card center, the view center would be moved also

Just change this line:

```
func createPanGestureRecognizer(_: UIView) {
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(#selector(self.panCard(_:))))
    gameCard.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)// Use gameCard to add gesture not parent view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When doing let card = view and card.center = view.center in the function, it gave me an error and told me to do card!.center = view.center, so I used that and now, nothing moves.

Comment: Im assuming this should go inside the if statement correct? I placed it inside the if statement, and now it returns to center again when you let go though, all the other items, UILabel, UIButton and View all move together at the same time (which is still the issue) (only trying to move the UIView)

Comment: Yes, try that code, let me explain: whenever you moved the card center, the view center would be moved also, so the center of the view is also same as the center of the card after the state of pan gesture is ended

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, now it returns to the center when you let go. Only problem is that everything moves together (UIbutton, label, and view, even though I only called on the view only) and the pan gesture is still very sensitive, it will go out of frame with the slightest touch (though now it returns to the center when you let go).

Comment: You want to move only the game card?

Comment: Yes, only trying to move the game card.

Comment: Omg, thank you for the help. Now everything works. Thanks again.

Comment: Right,  but that will constraint gesture must be happened inside the card. Brilliant.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation points, though I clicked the "accepted answer" button if that helps.

Comment: @Tam-ThanhLe I think you should tell people what their problem really is, not just how to fix. That’s a little bit tricky. Right?

Comment: Extremely amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

let card = sender.view!

Do not use the sender with you gesture callback method, it means which  view your gesture is attached to. In this context, it’s you self.view. So use you preferred view explicitly, having a property to refer to your white box may be sufficient.